# How to restore the state when changing, deleting?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I used vuex-persist to store the state in localStorage.

```
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    storage: localStorage
})

export default createStore({
    modules: {
        Auth
    },
    plugins: [
        vuexLocal.plugin
    ]
})
```

But when I change or delete localStorage directly, if I refresh the page, the entire application state is reset. Is there any way to fix this? And is this even necessary?

Tried using something like this in the root component (without vuex-persist):

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handleBeforeUnload);
    window.addEventListener('load', this.handleAfterUnload)
  }
```

That is, when refreshing the page to write all the state in the localStorage, and after it loads do the opposite. But I think that it is not reasonable to do so.